# How to get json/hash with that same keys and convert it json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I have problem with convert array with hashes to json. But i need to have that same keys in hash with different values.

```
elements = []
 portal_order_items.each do |product|
 elements << {"Kod":product.Kod,"Cena"=>product.price,"Ilosc"=>product.quantity}
 end
```

And i get something like this:

```
[{:Kod=>"M06006P0232", "Cena"=>"2.0", "Ilosc"=>1}, {:Kod=>"M06006P0019", "Cena"=>"53.0", "Ilosc"=>1}]
```

How chage it to json like this:

```
{"Kod":"M06006P0232", "Ilosc":1, "Cena":2.0,"Kod":"M06006P0019", "Ilosc":22, "Cena":53.0}
```

It need to be one json.. Anyone know solution of my problem ?

Comment: How are you converting to JSON? It works fine in console for me using both `to_json` and `JSON.dump`.

Comment: You dont see ? Its 1 json with duplicated keys - to_json gives to hashes..

Comment: I see it just fine. Using `to_json` and `JSON.dump` in my console, however, I can't replicate your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a string you need like this:

```
portal_order_items.map { |item| JSON.generate(item) }.join(',').gsub(/},{/, ',')
```

However, be advised that this JSON has duplicate keys. While this is *technically* correct (there is no explicit requirement for JSON document to have unique keys), most libraries out there will just keep the last key's value when parsing it. Most likely, this is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.map` to edit your array of `portal_order_items` and then you can covert to json using `.to_json` method.

See the docs for JSON [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

```
portal_order_items.map do |product|
  {"Kod":product.Kod,"Cena"=>product.price,"Ilosc"=>product.quantity}
end.to_json
```